# best way to optimize this sqlite database

Tags: sqlite

i have a sqlite database contains one table with this structure

```
CREATE TABLE stats (
    day_date          DATE     NOT NULL,
    listing_id        INT (10) NOT NULL,
    cat_id            INT (4)  DEFAULT (0),
    source_id         INT (4)  DEFAULT (0),
    views             INT (8)  NOT NULL
                               DEFAULT (0),
    views_counter     INT (8)  NOT NULL
                               DEFAULT (0),
    bot_views         INT (8)  NOT NULL
                               DEFAULT (0),
    bot_views_counter INT (8)  DEFAULT (0) 
                               NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (
        day_date
    )
);
```

[and this is the file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByED9YBICVmOeGN5d3dUVS1ldk0/view)

this database may contains 500,000 rows, so i want to make some indices to make the query fast

the query i use on this db is

```
SELECT listing_id,SUM(views) AS total_views
FROM stats
WHERE day_date IN("11-10-2015","12-10-2015","13-10-2015","14-10-2015",
                  "15-10-2015","16-10-2015","17-10-2015")
group by listing_id
ORDER BY total_views DESC
```

i use the range on day_date to get one day,one week entires,

i have some ideas , what about make a new column named 'week' contains the week number of the year and add index on it so if i want a day i will use only one value on `day_date` ,if i want a week i will use `week` column ... is that right?

Comment: How long does it take to execute?

Answer (score 1):

If you use the [correct date format](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime), you don't need to enumerate all the days in the week and can use a simple index on the date column:

```
... WHERE day_date BETWEEN '2015-10-11' AND '2015-10-17' ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I never use a DATE format. I use only TEXT, like "20151029223007" for October 29th of 2015, 22 hours, 30 minutes, 07 seconds. It's easy and fast to order and compare.

Then, you can write:

```
SELECT listing_id,SUM(views) AS total_views
FROM stats
WHERE day_date > "20151010" and day_date < "20151018"
group by listing_id
ORDER BY total_views DESC
```